# Inserting same item into HashSets in two different class instances

Tags: rust

In the code below, I define a type `Bird`, and then a type `Birdwatcher` which has a `HashSet` of `birds_seen`.

`Birdwatcher`s have a method `.see(bird)` which inserts a `bird` to their HashSet. (In context, this method has some other logic, so we cannot just call the hashset's `.insert()` method directly.)

In the `main()` function, I instantiate a bird as well as two birdwatchers. The code does not compile if I try to have both birdwatchers `.see()` the same bird:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let falcon = Bird { name: "falcon".to_string(), speed: 25 };

    let mut alice = Birdwatcher { name: "Alice".to_string(), birds_seen: HashSet::new() };
    let mut bobby = Birdwatcher { name: "Bobby".to_string(), birds_seen: HashSet::new() };

    alice.see(falcon);
    // use of moved value: `falcon`
    // bobby.see(falcon);
}

#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct Bird {
    name: String,
    speed: isize,
}

struct Birdwatcher {
    name: String,
    birds_seen: HashSet<Bird>,
}

impl Birdwatcher {
    fn see(&mut self, bird: Bird) {
        // Additional logic goes here
        self.birds_seen.insert(bird);
    }
}
```

I though I could fix this by changing the `.see()` method to borrow the bird, as below, but this does not compile due to mismatched types:

```rust
impl Birdwatcher {
    fn see(&mut self, bird: &Bird) {
        // mismatched types: expected `Bird`, found `&Bird`
        self.birds_seen.insert(bird);
    }
}
```

**How can I write the `.see()` method to allow the same bird to be seen by multiple birdwatchers?**

Comment: This is a basic feature of Rust and the borrow checker. You'll have to either clone the birds, use an Rc for shared ownership, or store some a copyable item that can be used to identity the bird, such as a reference or a numeric ID.

Comment: But you can store the birds in two different hashsets if you instantiate the hashsets directly using `HashSet::new()`. It's only when passing them through this other struct (`Birdwatcher`) that the problem emerges. So, I understand why the first example doesn't work, but my confusion is why my attempted fix (borrowing, not mutable, `bird: &Bird` in `.see()`) doesn't work—we shouldn't need to "use" the birds to store them in a hashset; we can just compute their hash (once) and add it to the set. (FWIW, a numeric ID is precisely the workaround I have been using.)

Comment: A HashSet can't just store the hash itself because it needs to resolve collisions, which can only be done when it has an existing item to compare against the new item (with `eq`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we shouldn't need to "use" the birds to store them in a hashset; we can just compute their hash (once) and add it to the set.

A `HashSet` is not a set *of hashes*; it is a set which *uses* hashes. It still contains, owns, the values that are inserted just like a `Vec` or any other regular collection type in Rust would.

This is necessary because the hashes may collide — they don't have enough bits to practically guarantee not colliding — in which case the set will have to fall back to comparing the values themselves with `Eq`. Additionally, `HashSet` allows iteration over the items, or removal of the items, so it must own them to be able to produce them.

If you want a set that stores only hashes, you will need to make a set of those hashes, not of the values that are hashed to produced them.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. But then I don't understand why removing the `Birdwatcher` class entirely and writing `let mut one = HashSet::new(); one.insert(&falcon); let mut two = HashSet::new(); two.insert(&falcon);` in the main function gets around this problem. Here we can add the bird to the hashset by borrowing, so it would seem that the hashset doesn't "own" the bird.

Comment: @Max In that case, because you used `&` in the `insert`, the type of the map is inferred as `HashSet<&Bird>`. It owns references. The `Birdwatcher` will do the same if you change the map type that way — but you may not like the restrictions this imposes, where _some other component_, not the map or the `Birdwatcher` must own the `Bird`s (trying to make it own them will cause lifetime errors).